# Where can I see my interest and dividends earned as well as net capital gain/loss for my Fidelity HSA last year?

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, dividends, hsa, fidelity

As I was a tax resident of California in 2021, I must report the interest and dividends earned as well as net capital gain/loss for my HSA account, which is managed by Fidelity:

[image]

Where can I see my interest and dividends earned as well as net capital gain/loss for my Fidelity HSA last year? Am I supposed to go through the history of Activity & Orders and compute them manually, or is there any document already containing this information?

Comment: For additional comments on California causing problems for HSA account owners see my answer here: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/25166/california-state-taxes-on-health-savings-accounts?rq=1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[littleadv](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/2998/littleadv)'s [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/150307/5656) is incorrect: one doesn't have to manually go through your transaction history and collect the information. Instead, Fidelity directly gives the information.

To view the dividends and interest, go to your 2021 year-end statement online, and find the following table in the HSA section:

[image]

[image]

On Page 13:

[image]

To view the net capital gain/loss, in the left column click on your HSA account, go to the "position" tab, and click on "closed positions":

[image]

Then select 2021, and it'll give you the net capital gain/loss for 2021:

[image]

Comment: Not sure why but my statement doesn't have this line, even though I certainly received dividends in my HSA in 2021.

Comment: @CraigW the end year statement contains all the accounts, so perhaps you looked at a table that isn't about your HSA? That's the mistake I did before posting the question.

Comment: For whatever reason my HSA has its own statements (the rest of my Fidelity accounts are on a consolidated statement), so I don't think that's it.

Comment: @CraigW weird, I added a few more screenshots if it helps.

Comment: I have the same year-end statement as you with 'Securities Bought' and 'Securities Sold' lines, but no 'Dividends' line for whatever reason. Oh well.

Comment: It only shows "income earned", doesn't tell me what is interest, what is dividend, so while it is nice of Fidelity to provide that - it's still not the information you're asking about in your question.

Comment: @littleadv you said "you're supposed to manually go through your transaction history and collect the information". That's incorrect for cap gain.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're supposed to manually go through your transaction history and collect the information. California doesn't conform to the Federal tax law in that regard, and since it's the only (almost, New Jersey is the only other one) State that does that the brokerage firms do not generally provide that information for California residents.

---

If you bank with Fidelity and are OK with filing incorrect tax return, you can follow the process outlined in Franck's answer. Keep in mind that the statement Franck refers to doesn't detail different income items (that are specifically mentioned in the question), so following it leads to a risk of incorrectly filling the tax return and getting burned on the FTB audit. In any case, Fidelity is under no obligation to provide any such statement, and has no guarantees to its correctness.

By tracing the transactions directly you have no such risk.